# How to automatically receive files in Skype Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, skype

When I used Skype in Ubuntu 13, there was an option to automatically receive files from our contacts. There was a checkbox & I had to just check it & after that files will be automatically downloaded when someone send it. So, every time I don't have to click on accept or ignore when a file is sent by someone. But now I use Windows Vista/7 & Skype version 6.16.0.105 & I don't see/have the option to receive files automatically?

How can I enable automatic receiving of files in Windows OS????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: [Automatically receiving files.](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Automatically-receiving-files/td-p/1224932)

> No. There are no settings available to automatically accept receiving file transfer. In any case, this would have been a huge security risk in the case someone would try to send you a malicious fail containing e.g. a virus.

It seems to be disabled.

Comment: It was available in the Skype I used in UBUNTU.There was under checkbox Tools->Options->General.

Answer (score 5):

Well..I found out. Thanks to me. :)

[image]

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Send-files-just-download-automatically-without-asking-me/m-p/3180088#M264766

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Automatic-File-Download/m-p/3189786